# Programmable Blocks give input variable

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, cms-block

Im currently trying to get some kind of rich snippets onto my cms blocks. For displaying the rich snippet I would like to add a block. This block needs to be able to receive some data from the current site.
Im currently using this on the cms pages:
`{{block type="core/template" name="my-template" template="path/to/template.phtml"}}`

Can I give some kind of data to this template? Something like
`{{block type="core/template" name="my-template" template="path/to/your/template.phtml?data=value"}}`

Is this possible this way or is there any other way to do this properly?

Another idea would be using the name of the block. How do I get the name of the block inside of the block?

Comment: have you tried the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you can pass data/parameters. Use code below:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="my-template" template="path/to/your/template.phtml" parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2" }}
```

You can pass as much parameters as you want.

At template, you can get the values of these parameters by :

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getParameter1();
    echo $this->getParameter2();
?>
```